# Running my file in node, terminal throwing error syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to run a file in my node environment on my macbook. I keep getting the following terminal error messages:

```
/.../filename.js: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/.../filename.js: line 2: `const fs = require('../build/index.js');'
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('../build/index.js');
```

The command I'm giving is:

```
node index.js
```

(I know the file names are the same but its calling a different file.)

I can't seem to figure out why it is finding the extra `.

I have tried:

- Rewriting the code multiple times.
- I started a new file from scratch with the same name (filename.js).
- Running the code through jslint
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-in-node-js-for-http
- I followed the exact formatting from this article: https://adrianmejia.com/blog/2016/08/12/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/
- Using double quotes instead of single quotes

Little more background, this is a project I've picked up and this is my first time trying to run it.

EDIT: Code for index.js

```
'use strict';

var _child_process = require('child_process');

var _logger = require('./logger');

var _logger2 = _interopRequireDefault(_logger);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var l = new _logger2.default();

l.log('Starting backup');
var wd = __dirname.split('/');
var basePath = wd.slice(0, wd.length - 1).join('/');
var execPath = basePath + '/path/filename.js';
var stdout = (0, _child_process.execSync)('. ' + execPath + ' -a ' + basePath + '/something.json -b ' + basePath + '/backups');

l.log(stdout);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192125/discussion-on-question-by-a-israfil-running-my-file-in-node-terminal-throwing-e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `index.js` calls `filename.js` through `child_process.execSync()` method, that's basically "execute this file using shell and give me its output".

Your `filename.js` has a shebang, and it would do intended (run using node), if not for this tiny dot in `execSync()` first parameter. It looks like this:

```
. /some/path/filename.js -a /some/path/something.json -b /some/path/backups
```

In `sh`-shells the `.` is a shorthand for `source` builtin command, that means "execute this file *in shell* and return its exit code". Thus, `filename.js` executes in shell, *not* in the node.

Just remove this dot (with space after it) and it will work.

Comment: Good news: You've solved this issue. Bad news: new error, cannot find module. Going to get to work on that now.